# pass dynamic URLs to require()

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

I need to loop through my products array then pass the data as props but for my image urls I cant do that and console show me the following:

```
invalid call at line 21 require(this.props.img)
```

here is my code:
**app.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        details: 'this is a macbook',
        image: '../Images/macbook.jpg',
        price: '1000$',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        details: 'this is a PS4 pro',
        image: '../Images/ps4pro.jpeg',
        price: '500$',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        details: 'this is a beats',
        image: '../Images/beats.jpeg',
        price: '200$',
      },
    ]
  }

  showProds = () => {
    let prods = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.products.length - 1; i++) {
      prods.push(<Product details={this.state.products[i].details} img={this.state.products[i].image} />)
    }
    console.log(prods);
    return prods;
  }

  render() {
    return <ScrollView>
      {this.showProds()}
    </ScrollView>
  }
}
```

**product component**

```
export default class Product extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.card}>
                <View style={styles.prod}>
                    <Text style={styles.prod_details}>{this.props.details}</Text>
                    <Image style={styles.img} source={require(this.props.img)} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.btn}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.btn_text}>Delete</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View >
        )
    }
}
```

I'm new to react-native. I also tried to use require in my loop but no luck.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your products.image so their will be in this format:

```
products: {
   ...
   image: require('.../Images.image.jpeg'),
   ...
}
```

And then change image source to this:

```
<Image style={styles.img} source={this.props.img} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant dynamically require images in react-native. It's a major flaw in react native.

You have two options,

1.Either host the images onany server like cloudinary and send the URI
2.You can require all images at start, and then just include those image components like :

```
const flower = () => (

<Image source={require('../../)} />

)




const rat = () => (
    
    <Image source={require('../../)} />
    
    )
```

and  `(this.props.img == 'flower') ? flower():rat()`

Hope you get the gyst. Feel free for doubts